# How can I get Month Difference from two dates which are stored in Table in the format YYYYMM

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

My table has a column date_period which stores Date in the format **YYYYMM**. I want to write a query which inserts date in date_period column in the format **YYYYMM** if there is no entry till current month.

For Example: the date period has entry till October 2015 so it will contain the value **201510**. Now I want to check and insert data till current month if it is not present. So the entries will be now **201511, 201512, 201601**

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Convert them to date using Convert(); then perform DateDiff by Month.

Comment: @munmun whats is the data type date_period column you taken?

Comment: @MeerDeen its **int** data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> try this way, may it will help you

```
DECLARE @v DATE= getdate()
declare @Currentdate varchar(10)
set  @Currentdate=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @v, 112)
/*@Currentdate string is in format '20160129'*/
IF NOT EXISTS(select * from Table1 where  date_period=LEFT(@Currentdate,6))
begin
 insert into Table1(date_period)values(LEFT(@Currentdate,6))
end
```

## Try this

i think this will be the complete solution for your problem

```
declare @monthcount int
DECLARE @v DATE= getdate()
declare @lastsavedMonth varchar(20)= (select MAX(date_period) from Table1)
declare @Lastsaveddate varchar(20)= @lastsavedMonth+''+RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, 100 + DATEPART(d,@v)), 2)

set @monthcount=datediff(month,@Lastsaveddate,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @v, 112))

while @monthcount>=0
        begin
                declare @dateofsavingmonth varchar(20)
                if(@monthcount=0)
                    begin
                    set @dateofsavingmonth=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@v,112)
                    end
                else
                   begin
                     set @dateofsavingmonth=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(month,-@monthcount,@v),112)
                   end

                    IF NOT EXISTS(select * from Table1 where  date_period=LEFT(@dateofsavingmonth,6))
                    begin
                     insert into Table1(date_period)values(LEFT(@dateofsavingmonth,6))
                    end
                set @monthcount =@monthcount-1
        end
```

Comment: I had already did this as if the current month date does not exists then it will add that date to date_period column. But my problem is how can I detect how much months are not inserted till current month. In the example above i have inserted date till October month only, now I want to insert remaining months date till current month.

Comment: Can you please explain the line:
declare @Lastsaveddate varchar(20)= @lastsavedMonth+''+RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, 100 + DATEPART(d,@v)), 2)

Comment: @lastsavedmonth is your last saved entry like **201505**

Comment: understood I want to know how you calculated @Lastsaveddate

Comment: year and month from saved @Lastsavedmonth like 2015 and month is 05

Comment: and day from current date

Comment: @lastsaved date is taken temporarly bases

Comment: RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, 100 + DATEPART(d,@v)), 2) is used to take day from currentdate.it will return the day in two digits

Comment: @lastsaved  will be look like this **20150501*